# gamedev tag is useless

Tags: discussion, tags

I see some questions tagged as [gamedev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gamedev). A similar issue was addressed on Stack Overflow Meta [a while back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3127/please-remove-the-programming-tag).

**Recommendation:** This tag is useless and should never be used, since everything on this Game Dev site should be about Game Dev anyway.

*Edit:* I've removed all the gamedev tags I can

Comment: I agree. The tag is redudant, and should be removed

Comment: +1 I Agree: No need in the tag

Comment: Agreed. The tag must go.

Comment: See also: http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/155/the-these-tags-are-useless-thread

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be solved. The gamedev tag no longer exists.